# how to set spring data one-indexed pagination

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I just have a little problem where i can't figure out how to set one-indexed pagination. I'm using a rest-Api (extending jpaRepository)

I already tried some suggestion on the web (including stackoverflow ones) but it doesn't work for me, I tried a config file using "WebMvcConfigurerAdapter" but it's deprecated so i didn't go further. Isn't there a simple property i can append to my properties file to activate one-indexed pagination ?
I also tried setting this property (spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=true) but it doesn't affect my application at all...

I want to use a GET request returning 10 items, but with one-indexed pagination

```
    public Page<Station> findAll(@RequestParam() int page,Pageable pageable) {
        return stationRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, 10));
        //return stationRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

This requests still shows me 0-indexed items and index-1 is the second page...etc. I expect it to be 1-indexed (page 1 should return the first items on my database)

**EDIT:** 
The pagination issue can be solved by setting the request page number to (page-1) from the server side :

```
    public Page<Station> findAll(@RequestParam() int page,Pageable pageable) {
        return stationRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page-1, 10));
        //return stationRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

But the initial problem (setting one-indexed server pagination) still persists

Comment: just curious - can you not use `PageRequest.of(page-1, 10)` to take care of this?

Comment: Indeed, i initially tried to do the trick from the client side but i had some problems with async code. i didn't thaught about doing it in the server side thanks for the that. It solves my particular issue but i'm still curious about my initial question. Let me know if you ahve any clue.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer pageableCustomizer() {
        return (resolver) -> {
            resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
        };
    }
}
```